# Keep extra whitespaces while writing pandas dataframe to file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, io, whitespace

How do I keep extra whitespaces from columns while writing a dataframe to a file?

Say I have this dataframe, while printing the dataframe I can see the whitespaces. `to_csv()` from pandas, however, strips the whitespaces while writing to file. Whitespaces are even preserved, if I write the dataframe to file as string with `file.write(str(df))`, but this does not maintain the tabular format because the length of string in a column is long.

```
a   |   b   |     c        | d
------------------------------
10  |   1   |     100      | d
20  |   2   |     10       | d
```

The number of whitespaces varies in each rows because it depends on the column value. For example, for column `c`, second row has one more whitespace than the first row because the value in the first row is one char longer.

For context, I am reading the dataframe from a file, with `pd.read_csv()` the whitespaces are preserved. After manipulating the dataframe, I again want to write it to another file, but `to_csv()` isn't preserving whitespaces. Other variant such as `np.savetxt()` or any other approach is okay.

Edit: I found that columns have `tab` instead of spaces, how do I deal with this?

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` for reproducibility

Comment: @mozway, `df.to_dict()` also strips extra whitespaces from the columns and keeps only one

Comment: No it doesn't: `pd.DataFrame({'   col ': ['   123 ']}).to_dict()` -> `{'   col ': {0: '   123 '}}`

Comment: If every column in your DataFrame is of Type `object` then the whitespaces will also appear in your csv-file. `object` basically means a string-type. However, if you read data from a csv file Pandas likely tries to find the correct datatype assigning numeric data types. This is not valid for column captions. These are usually strings.

Comment: Now, I am even more confused because for the given example, even `to_csv` preserves the whitespaces. For my original problem, it does not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please read the edit, I  found that columns have tab instead of spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *by design*. Strictly speaking, the CSV format mandates that no extra space occurs between the delimiter and the field - even if most readers can be configured to ignore them. But as `to_csv` writes conformant files, it will never write extra spaces.

What you want is not a csv file but a Fixed Width Fields file. You can generate one with `to_string` with `df.to_string(filename)`. It will be close to what you obtain when printing the dataframe on your screen, but its [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.htm) references a number of parameters, for example `col_space` can be used to fix the minimum width for the columns:

```
df.to_string(filename, col_space=[5, 5, 8, 5], index=None)
```

will write it with no index and ensure that colums a, b, and d and at least 5 characters wide, and c at least 8 characters wide.

Comment: Thank you, this is very promising. One more question, how do I align the string to left in column while writing as string? I want all the column values to start from the same point, but now in the file, it looks like there are trailing whitespaces for the shorter strings. This is what I mean: https://pastebin.com/H64dWiFW

Comment: This looks like a different question. I can also create another question, if you want

Comment: I tried `justify=left` but it only moves column name to left

Comment: Left alignment is not easy. But anyway you should be aware that the file you have showned in your pastebin will be hard to read with `read_csv` because some fields contains spaces... Anyway I shall soon post a way for left alignment.

Comment: I don't need to read it again with `read_csv`. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have also created a separate question for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824553/how-to-left-align-column-values-in-pandas-to-string). I will accept your answer for this.