# How to left align column values in pandas `to_string()`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, io, tostring

I want to save a pandas dataframe to a file with `to_string()`, but want to left align the column values. With  `to_string(justify=left)`, only column labels are left aligned.

For example with

`pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['   123 ', ' 1234'], 'col2': ['1', '444441234']}).to_string(index=False)`

I get the following result:

[image]

I want to get rid of the whitespaces in the first row by left aligning the column values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to_string` methods provides support for per column *formatters*. It allows you to use specific formats for all of some columns. A rather simple way is to create a format and then apply it with a lambda. The only picky part is that to use left formatting, you will have to know the width of the column.

For your provided data, you could left align everything with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['   123 ', ' 1234'], 'col2': ['1', '444441234']})
widths = [4, 9]
formats = ['{' + f':<{i}' + '}' for i in widths]
print(df.to_string(index=None, col_space=widths, formatters=
                   [(lambda x: fmt.format(x)) for fmt in formats],
                   justify='left'))
```

to get:

```
col1       col2      
    123     1        
  1234      444441234
```

You could also left align only some columns by using a dict for the formatters parameter:

```
print(df.to_string(index=None, formatters=
                   {'col2': (lambda x: '{:<9}'.format(x))},
                   justify='left'))
```

gives:

```
col1     col2      
    123   1        
    1234  444441234
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to justify the strings yourself:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['   123 ', ' 1234'], 'col2': ['1', '444441234']})
   .apply(lambda s: (s:=s.astype(str).str.strip()).str.ljust(s.str.len().max()))
   .to_string(index=False, justify='left')
)
```

*NB. this requires python 3.8+ due to the walrus operator, if you have an earlier version, use a function instead.*

```
def ljust(s):
    s = s.astype(str).str.strip()
    return s.str.ljust(s.str.len().max())

(pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['   123 ', ' 1234'], 'col2': ['1', '444441234']})
   .apply(ljust)
   .to_string(index=False, justify='left')
)
```

Output:

```
col1 col2     
123  1        
1234 444441234
```

Comment: Thank you, is it also possible to only do this for a column instead of a whole dataframe?